Can Excel formulas containing nested worksheet functions be used and referenced within VBA code?
There are two separate but related things that I'm trying to accomplish in VBA in an Excel workbook that I'm developing, neither of which I seem to be doing correctly. I've numbered them and separated them into sections below.

1.) I'm trying to use a formula consisting of multiple nested worksheet functions in a VBA module the same way that I'm already using it on a worksheet. I'm more experienced with worksheet functions and formulas than I am with VBA functions and code, and the majority of formulas I create are long and complex with multiple nested worksheet functions and, if necessary, user-defined worksheet functions.
This is the formula that I'm trying to use in a VBA module:
=YEAR(DATE(TEXTBEFORE(TEXTAFTER(@CELL("filename",$A$1),"[",1)," ",1),1,1))

To better explain what I'm trying to accomplish, I'll describe how the formula is used. We have several Excel workbooks that we use to keep track of different things on a yearly basis, with new ones getting created at the start of each year. As each workbook keeps track of different things, there's really no one-size-fits-all way for me to describe the workbook elements and functionality, so for the purposes of the following questions I'm going to be asking, I'll use the hypothetical scenario that we're using the workbooks in question to keep track of how many apples we've picked over the course of a year.
All of the workbooks in question are stored on OneDrive and synced to several of our computers via the OneDrive desktop app. The first four characters of the filename of most of these workbooks comprise the workbook's associated year (in my hypothetical scenario, the workbook is named "2024 Apple Picking"). As a result, I create a single template workbook for each individual thing that we're trying to keep track of, and instead of an associated year, I use the year "1900" as the first four characters of the template workbook's filename (maybe not the best choice given the whole Excel-leap-year thing, but I digress). When a new year starts, I create a copy of the template workbook and change the year in the copy's filename from "1900" to whatever the current year is, at which point the copy becomes an active workbook.
I use the above formula to return whatever year is present in the first four characters of the workbook's filename for use in several other formulas on several worksheets. What I wanted to do was use this formula to pass the year that's present in the filename to VBA (I'll get to more on why in a moment). Going off of this, I created this test procedure in the template workbook to see if VBA would return the "1900" from its filename:
Private Sub Test_1()

    Test_variable_1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.YEAR(DATE(TEXTBEFORE(TEXTAFTER(@CELL("filename",$A$1),"[",1)," ",1),1,1))
    
    MsgBox Test_variable_1

End Sub

but when I tried to run it, the Visual Basic Editor presented me with a message box that reads "Compile error: Syntax error" and the procedure wouldn't run. I tried replacing all of the quotation marks in the formula with apostrophes (as I understand it, that's a way of escaping the quotation marks) so that it looked like this:
Private Sub Test_1()

    Test_variable_1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.YEAR(DATE(TEXTBEFORE(TEXTAFTER(@CELL('filename',$A$1),'[',1),' ',1),1,1))
    
    MsgBox Test_variable_1

End Sub

but I didn't have any luck that way either; first, the Visual Basic Editor highlighted the "TEXTBEFORE" worksheet function in the formula and displayed "Compile error: Expected: )", and when I tried to run it, I got "Compile error: Syntax error" again. Based on what I read here, I'm not sure if that's because the worksheet functions that I used in the formula are not available to VBA, or if it's because you just can't use nested worksheet functions in VBA, or both.
I suppose I could put the formula in a cell on a new behind-the-scenes worksheet and tell the VBA code to run based on whether or not the formula result equals "1900" (behind-the-scenes worksheets are worksheets which I password protect and hide as they contain formulas that other formulas rely on, LinkedCell property value assignments connected to ActiveX controls, and other things of this nature that I can't have users potentially messing with).
I believe I know how to do that in VBA because I think I've done it before on at least one other of our workbooks, but I've got all of my behind-the-scenes worksheets named and organized according to what they contain, and as none of them currently contain formulas of this nature, it felt like it would make more sense to use the formula directly in the VBA code if possible. Unless there's a third option and it's possible to use VBA directly to return the first four characters of the workbook's filename? Would anyone know if that's possible?

2.) I'm trying to use VBA to insert one of the long, complex formulas that I referenced above into a cell on the "Apple Picking History" worksheet. This is the formula:
=EXPAND(IF(IFERROR(SORT(FILTER('<file path to the workbook's location in OneDrive>[1900 Apple Picking.xlsm]Apple Picking'!$A$4:$H$10003,'<file path to the workbook's location in OneDrive>[1900 Apple Picking.xlsm]Apple Picking'!$A$4:$A$10003 = Filter_selection_current_apple_name,""),2,-1,FALSE),"") = 0,"",IFERROR(SORT(FILTER('<file path to the workbook's location in OneDrive>[1900 Apple Picking.xlsm]Apple Picking'!$A$4:$H$10003,'<file path to the workbook's location in OneDrive>[1900 Apple Picking.xlsm]Apple Picking'!$A$4:$A$10003 = Filter_selection_current_apple_name,""),2,-1,FALSE),"")),10000,8,"")

It's an array formula that is located in cell A7 of the "Apple Picking History" worksheet and expands right to column I and down to row 10006. The data in the array formula is looked up from where it is stored on the "Apple Picking" worksheet in the "1900 Apple Picking" workbook and displayed on the corresponding "Apple Picking History" worksheet in the "1900 Apple Picking History" workbook. The data will be comprised of many entries, one entry per row, extending across an indeterminate number of rows which will gradually increase as the year progresses from January through December, which is why I made the return range of the array formula so large (I don't think that's exactly helping the calculation speed of the workbook, but that's another issue entirely).
"Filter_selection_current_apple_name" is a defined name that refers to cell A1 on the "(Filter Selections)" worksheet, which I assigned to the LinkedCell property of the List Box ActiveX control that's placed on the "Apple Picking History" worksheet (the "(Filter Selections)" worksheet is one of my behind-the-scenes worksheets). The List Box ActiveX control lists different types of apples (for example, "Granny Smith 1", "Granny Smith 2", "Macintosh 1", "Macintosh 2", "Red Delicious 1", "Red Delicious 2", and so on).
The user can click on one type of apple at a time to view its associated apple picking history data. The List Box currently has over 100 values listed in it, but it's possible for more or less values to be listed over time as the total number of values dynamically fluctuates based on data changed by the user in the "Apple Inventory" workbook. When a user clicks on a type of apple in the List Box, the apple picking history data displayed by the array formula dynamically changes to display only the data for the apple type that the user clicked.
I created two different test procedures to test the process of inserting the formula into cell M1 on the "Apple Picking History" worksheet (as mentioned above, the formula would ultimately need to be inserted into cell A7 on the "Apple Picking History" worksheet, but as I don't want to overwrite the active array formula that's already there, I used cell M1 as my insertion test cell as it's a blank cell located away from my used cells and surrounded by other blank cells). Both of the test procedures are stored in the "Apple Picking History" worksheet's corresponding module. These are the test procedures:
Private Sub Test_2()
    
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Apple Picking History").Range("M1").Formula = _
    "=EXPAND(IF(IFERROR(SORT(FILTER('<file path to the workbook's location in OneDrive>[1900 Apple Picking.xlsm]Apple Picking'!$A$4:$H$10003,'<file path to the workbook's location in OneDrive>[1900 Apple Picking.xlsm]Apple Picking'!$A$4:$A$10003 = Filter_selection_current_apple_name,""),2,-1,FALSE),"") = 0,"",IFERROR(SORT(FILTER('<file path to the workbook's location in OneDrive>[1900 Apple Picking.xlsm]Apple Picking'!$A$4:$H$10003,'<file path to the workbook's location in OneDrive>[1900 Apple Picking.xlsm]Apple Picking'!$A$4:$A$10003 = Filter_selection_current_apple_name,""),2,-1,FALSE),"")),10000,8,"")"

End Sub

Private Sub Test_3()

    Dim Test_variable_3 As Range
    
    Set Test_variable_3 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Apple Picking History").Range("M1")
    
    Test_variable_3.Formula = _
    "=EXPAND(IF(IFERROR(SORT(FILTER('<file path to the workbook's location in OneDrive>[1900 Apple Picking.xlsm]Apple Picking'!$A$4:$H$10003,'<file path to the workbook's location in OneDrive>[1900 Apple Picking.xlsm]Apple Picking'!$A$4:$A$10003 = Filter_selection_current_apple_name,""),2,-1,FALSE),"") = 0,"",IFERROR(SORT(FILTER('<file path to the workbook's location in OneDrive>[1900 Apple Picking.xlsm]Apple Picking'!$A$4:$H$10003,'<file path to the workbook's location in OneDrive>[1900 Apple Picking.xlsm]Apple Picking'!$A$4:$A$10003 = Filter_selection_current_apple_name,""),2,-1,FALSE),"")),10000,8,"")"

End Sub

Unfortunately, neither of the test procedures actually run; when I try to run either of them, the Visual Basic Editor gives me a message box that reads "Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error". So then I created another test procedure based on the example given by Microsoft here, but containing slightly modified code repurposed to my situation (like my first two test procedures, I stored this test procedure in the "Apple Picking History" worksheet's corresponding module):
Private Sub Test_4()

    Worksheets("Apple Picking History").Range("M1").Formula = "=RAND()"

End Sub

This test procedure runs without issue and successfully inserts the RAND worksheet function into cell M1 on the "Apple Picking History" worksheet. So if that's an indication that a.) VBA can be used to insert only singular worksheet functions and not formulas consisting of nested worksheet functions, or b.) VBA can be used to insert formulas but not ones as long and complex as mine, or c.) both of the above, then I guess I'm essentially back to square one.
The reason that I need to be able to do this has to do with my template workbook concept that I described above. The idea behind creating this system of template workbooks transitioning into active workbooks is that each template workbook is essentially a master copy, so that when updates to the formulas, behind-the-scenes worksheets, VBA code, etc. are required, I can make those updates once in a template workbook and then create copies of it and/or export and import its VBA modules to more quickly apply the updates en masse to all existing active workbooks that originated from that template workbook, sort of like how a new update or patch is applied to existing software.
Ultimately, the whole point of the system is to enable me to quickly and efficiently a.) put active workbooks in place, and b.) apply fixes and features to those active workbooks as necessary, such that I can create a copy of a template workbook, change the year in the copy's filename, and go about my day with no further editing required to the copy. However, the array formula throws a wrench in the works.
This is because the "1900 Apple Picking" and "1900 Apple Picking History" template workbooks are saved in a different OneDrive subfolder and thus at different file paths than the "YYYY Apple Picking" and "YYYY Apple Picking History" copies will be saved to when they become active workbooks, meaning that the file path used in the array formula cannot remain the same in any copies that are made of the "1900 Apple Picking History" template workbook as the array formula will now be looking in the wrong place for the necessary data.
I would normally use worksheet functions like SWITCH, IF, and/or CONCATENATE to solve such a problem; for example, in this same template workbook, I'm using a user-defined COMPUTERNAME worksheet function in conjunction with HYPERLINK, SWITCH, and CONCATENATE to return links to where the actual apple picking reports are stored on OneDrive because they're synced locally and the file path to the local OneDrive folder differs depending on the computer being used to access it. However, though I've been using CONCATENATE to Frankenstein together hyperlink URLs for years, I've never attempted to do the same with references to cells or ranges, which, as I've recently discovered, is apparently not possible.
As a result, the only solution to this problem that I can think of would be to create a procedure that would run on workbook open and check the four-digit year in the workbook's filename to see if it's anything other than "1900", and if so, insert a different array formula (that targets the active workbook's file path) over the existing array formula (that targets the template workbook's file path) in cell A7 on the "Apple Picking History" worksheet — hence the above two things that I'm trying to accomplish. I believe creating such a procedure would essentially equate to including working versions of my above test procedures in an If...Then...Else statement, provided that someone can help me figure out how to get them to work in the way that I need them to.
The problem with that is that after initially running and inserting the different array formula, the procedure would then needlessly waste the user's time by running unnecessarily every single time that an active workbook is opened because the four-digit year in an active workbook's filename will always be something other than "1900" no matter what. To account for this, I was thinking that I would need to use VBA to somehow check if the procedure had already run so that it didn't run again if it didn't need to — would anyone know of a way that I could do that?
I guess I could use VBA to look at the formula text of the array formula in cell A7 on the "Apple Picking History" worksheet to check whether is contains the active workbook's file path or the template workbook's file path and either run or not run the procedure accordingly. However, as that would entail referencing (though not actually using) worksheet functions and formulas in VBA code, that "solution" would theoretically encounter the exact same problems that I described above.
I'm always open to alternate methods of doing anything if anyone can think of any; as I said, I'm not 100% certain that what I'm attempting to do here is even possible.

When writing a formula to a cell, it's easier to Debug.Print first and inspect the output in the Immediate Window. If you copy/paste the output to a cell, Excel may flag the problematic portion. Side note: dynamic array formulas should be written with .Formula2, not .Formula.

"replacing all of the quotation marks in the formula with apostrophe" sounds off. Normally you would double up the quotes.

Why not just use Test_variable_1 = Left(ThisWorkbook.Name,4) ?

You need to shorten the question by 10 times. Downvoted.

I wouldn't do any of this. Use a Power Query (Data tab) to scan the sharepoint folder. Find the workbook based on some logic. Load Query to sheet. Now you have the name of the workbook which can be dynamically used in formulae.

This is what I can say after a quick read:

It's a good practice to use any available application feature instead of program it yourself.
To use a worksheet function in VBA, call it by any of those ways (the Sort function for e.g.):

a = Application.Sort(...
b = WorksheetFunction.Sort(...
ab = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sort(...

It should be written following the VBA syntax:
c = Application.Sort(arg1, arg2, etc.)


Alternatively, you can evaluate any worksheet expression calling the Evaluate function:

d = Evaluate("FORMULA")

The formula should be written following formula rules, with international localization:
d = Evaluate("SORT(A2:B10, 1)")

Since the Evaluate function is not linked to any cell, there is no difference between relative and absolute addressing in the evaluated expression.
You can omit the equal sign at the start. The string argument can be composed with string operations:
e = Evaluate("SORT(A2:A" & i & ")")

The double-quote letter inside the formula should be doubled following VBA rules for strings.

To debug mixed formulas/functions, first debug Excel formulas on a worksheet but VBA functions calling them from the code. Then use verified formulas/functions in cross-calls.
To write formula to a cell or range, use Formula2 or Formula2R1C1 properties. Sometimes a formula can be expressed easily following the R1C1 style.

Useful links:

VBA Worksheet Functions: 5 Ways To Easily Use Excel Functions In VBA
How to Use Worksheet Functions like VLOOKUP in VBA Excel?
Create custom functions in Excel
Description of limitations of custom functions in Excel

